# AngularJS - Table template based on type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm having some difficult figuring out how to solve this.

I have tabs (one for each Area) and inside of them one table for each Resource. The code for the Area looks like this:

```
app.controller("AreasController", function () {
    this.areas = [
        {
            name: "Area",
            value: 5,
            resources: [
                'type1',
                'type2'
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Area 2",
            value: 10,
            resources: [
                'type1',
                'type3'
            ]
        },
    ];
});
```

And the HTML have a div with `ng-repeat="area in areas.area"`.

What I'm a bit confused on how to do is the resources since each resource have a different table template and data (eg: type1 have Name and Age, type2 have Day, month and Year, etc.).

Can anyone please suggest a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If your tabs are totally different contents, then maybe you don't do a repeat and you "unroll" manually the tabs. If you have some similar parts between the tabs you can share code via directives. If you think the tabs are so similar that you still feel they should be in an ng-repeat, then you can use [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) or [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to conditionally render different types. For ngSwitch you would have some kind of type identifier in the model then you would switch on that type and have a case for your Person (name and age) and your Calendar (day/month/year). ngInclude is definitely the heavy-weight of the two options and makes sense if there is a lot of code in the switch, if you have a lot of types, or if you want to dynamically define types in the model side. With ngInclude you would create a separate partial view (HTML template) for each type you wanted to render. In the model you would reference that templates name. For example you might have `ng-include="resource.templateName"` where template name could be things like `/views/Person.html` and `/views/Calendar.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` along with `ng-include`

```
<div ng-repeat="area in areas">
    <div ng-repeat="resource in area.resources">
        <div ng-if="resource == 'type1'">
            <div ng-include="'type1_temlate.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="resource == 'type2'">
            <div ng-include="'type2_temlate.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: You can even use `ng-switch`

Answer (score 0):

Also,  give a look at 'UI Router' library.  Might make your implementation easier ;)